# How can I view the contents of the iOS app document director?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to troubleshoot my app, and I think my images are being saved properly to the directory, but I don't know how to view the directory to confirm. I just need to print the file list to the console. How can I do that using Swift 4?

Comment: See the docs for `FileManager`.

Comment: The linked duplicate fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

it print all file in document Directory

```
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
if let allItems = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentDirectory) {
    print(allItems)
}
```

you may copy path and open in finder as well.

Comment: I got it to print out `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/54896CC4-D6AB-49E3-BF83-35ABABDE4B6F/Documents/` but that isn't working when I try to go there in Finder. I have to run on device as it involves the camera, so not sure if that is part of the issue as I assume that path is on my iPhone and not on my iMac.

Comment: this code will also print file if those will exist.